# ValidateAntiForgeryToken and Authorize timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ActionResult decorated with ValidateAntiForgeryToken and Authorize.  Once my forms authorization timeout limit is reached, I'm receiving a "*A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid*" error instead of being routed to my login page.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`

> 'Represents an attribute that is used to detect whether a server
>   request has been tampered with.'

to quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx). What `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` does is output a hidden field into the form, something like: `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="XXX" />`.

What the `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` does on post back is compare the posted value to a previously stored cookie, to verify that they match. See http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#338576 (the `OnAuthorization` method) for details. The cookie has a name of **RequestVerificationToken_Lw** (you can use a cookie inspection tool like [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) to see this).

The cookie stored is a session cookie (the important bit). This means that when your authorization timeout is reached (30 mins by default in .NET), the cookie expires, doesn't get sent with the next request and the comparison to the hidden field value fails, throwing a `HttpAntiForgeryException`.

Comment: Thanks for the response...  I'm not quite sure how to fix this.  Basically, I want the <Authorize> attribute to execute before the <ValidateAntiForgeryToken> and route the user to my login page.  Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Action filter attributes execute in the order in which they were added, so if you add Authorize before ValidateAntiForgeryToken then it will work. Alternatively you can you the Order property to change the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() with in the BeginForm(){....} in the view

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm()){
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     .
     .
     .
     .
    }
```

Then this will be validated in the action filter attribute `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

Comment: I am already doing this.  My anti-forgery logic is working as expected except when the <Authroize> timeout limit has been exceeded.  Then I receive the "A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid" error.